# Convert a specific part of html to image using WebBrowser

Tags: c#

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- something -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- some tags -->
    <ifram>
      <html>
        <head>
          <!-- something -->
        </head>
        <body>
          <!-- some tags -->
            <table>
            </table>
          <!-- some tags -->
        </body>
      </html>
    </ifram>  
    <!-- some tags -->
  </body>
</html>
```

I found a solution for converting entire content of html to image, but I want to a specific part of it. in my html pages there is one table element and I want to convert the table to image and I don't want remain elements. below the code that i found, there is a way to modify the code for my purpose?

```
public Bitmap GenerateScreenshot(string url, int width, int height)
    {
        // Load the webpage into a WebBrowser control
        WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
        wb.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
        wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        wb.Navigate(url);
        while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) { Application.DoEvents(); }

        // Set the size of the WebBrowser control
        wb.Width = width;
        wb.Height = height;

        if (width == -1)
        {
            // Take Screenshot of the web pages full width
            wb.Width = wb.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width;
        }

        if (height == -1)
        {
            // Take Screenshot of the web pages full height
            wb.Height = wb.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height;
        }

        // Get a Bitmap representation of the webpage as it's rendered in the WebBrowser control
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(wb.Width, wb.Height);
        wb.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, wb.Width, wb.Height));
        wb.Dispose();

        return bitmap;
    }
```

Comment: Has this Table-Element a unique name or position on the WebPage? Please provide more infos about the conditions to find that table

Comment: As an idea, you can use external tool, which I believe is accessible for Windows as well - `wkhtmltopdf`, it contains both PDF generator and image generator (`wkhtmltoimage` I think it was named) and it is very reliable (since wk stands for WebKit). You can spawn a process with the desired content, passed as argument. I believe this would be less resource intensive that generating a WebBrowser component (instance of IE).

Comment: i put the exact the html dom in my post, it just have one "table" element in it's dom